# typeof(data) returns "object' by data[0] is undefined in Angular

Tags: angular

I was trying to get some data from the url: https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries

I am receiving this data through a service in my component.
But I can't access each JSON object separately.

Service:

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class CollectdataService {
  url: string = "https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries";
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}
  getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.url);
  }
}
```

Component:

```js
import { CollectdataService } from "./../services/collectdata.service";
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: "app-countrywise",
  templateUrl: "./countrywise.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./countrywise.component.css"],
})
export class CountrywiseComponent implements OnInit {
  id: string;
  data;
  idData;
  constructor(
    public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    public collectData: CollectdataService
  ) {
    this.id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data = this.collectData.getData().subscribe((data) => {
      // console.log(data);
      // this.data = data.splice(1);
      // console.log(this.data);
      // console.log(typeof(data));
    });
    console.log(typeof this.data);
  }
}
```

Comment: what you want to achieve explain it.

Answer (score 0):

See this stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-keyvaluepipe-demo-bnszod

added data in table format.

Answer (score 0):

I think u are confusing this.data and data

see u are assigning this.data to subscription coming from subscribe method
and data is just a local property coming from function

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
        this.data = this.collectData.getData().subscribe((data) => {
          // console.log(data);
          // this.data = data.splice(1);
          // console.log(this.data);
          // console.log(typeof(data));
        });
        console.log(typeof this.data);
      }
```

I think u need

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
         this.collectData.getData().subscribe((data) => {
         this.data = data
          // console.log(data);
          // this.data = data.splice(1);
          // console.log(this.data);
          // console.log(typeof(data));
        }); 

    console.log(typeof this.data);
  }
```

other then that every thing is fine

[image]